# Endless Scroll without polling (real time)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, scroll

how can you manage and endless scroll using a real time server connection instead pooling each time the user come to the end of the list on nodejs and react?
thanks

Comment: User pagination on the server and manage that on the frontend, when you react to end of list then try to fetch next page data and just assign that data to the reactive variable. it will bind on FE after that. It can't be possible to fetch at once if number of records are more line in 5-6K+, you need to call API each time for better UI/UX.

Answer (score 0):

User pagination on the server and manage that on the frontend, when you react to end of the list then try to fetch next page data and just assign that data to the reactive variable. it will bind on FE after that.

It can't be possible to fetch at once if the number of records are more like in 5-6K+ range. If you fetch at once then it will take more than one min maybe more than that, so until the user can't wait on the same page he might reload the page or leave the page. you need to call API each time for better UI/UX.

You can use directives like this.

Just focus on scroll if you get events like user reached the end of the list then simply print something like this (use opacity to get more focus)

[image]

if your API returns zero new data then just print something like this
[image]

Edit after comment:
No, you don't need to set an open connection to the server, just call an API when you reach the end of the list, like you calling only when you want to fetch more data from the server.
if you fetch the live data and you think that duplicates might be present then you can filter at the backend and remove duplicates via matching unique key. if that's not feasible then you can remove on FE also because you have less no of data on FE as compare to BE.
SO like if you're calling a third party API to get data, so first fetch all records if you can and store on your DB then call an API from your FE to get data from your own DB it will make a simple and fast rendering.

Comment: thanks but what about an open connection with the server? how should i implement it? moreover if you scroll form a live source you can get duplicates on the next page because the items change. How to solve it? thanks